# ¿Por qué no me elimina el directorio y todo su contenido?

Tags: c, linux, shell

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para poder eliminar un directorio y su contenido.

En el problema que me mandan resolver, tengo que hacer un shell, al cual le tengo que pasar un comando con sus argumentos para que haga una operación u otra, como en una ventana de comando de linux.

Mi problema viene con la operación ***eliminate***, en la cual la sintaxis es la siguiente:

**eliminate [-f] nombre**

Donde nombre es un fichero o un directorio y "-f" es opcional.

Si pongo ***eliminate directorio*** solo se puede eliminar el directorio si está vacío.

Si pongo ***eliminate fichero*** elimino el fichero.

Si solo pongo ***eliminate*** no hago nada.

Y por último si pongo ***eliminate -f directorio*** elimino el directorio y su contenido.

Si no se puede eliminar el fichero tengo que lanzar un aviso.

Mi problema viene con la última operación, las demás me funcionan. Cuando intento eliminar un directorio que contiene ficheros y uso la opción -f para eliminar el directorio y su contenido me saca el mensaje de "imposible borrar" y no se la razón por la que no me elimina el directorio. En el directorio que quiero eliminar tiene ficheros

Adjunto código:

```
int TrocearCadena(char * cadena, char * trozos[]){ //Devuelve el numero de palabras que hay en la cadena introducida
    int i=1;
    if ((trozos[0]=strtok(cadena," \n\t"))==NULL)
        return 0;
    while ((trozos[i]=strtok(NULL," \n\t"))!=NULL)
        i++;    
    return i;
}

int EsDirectorio(char *nombre) {
    struct stat s;
    if (lstat(nombre,&s)==-1)
        return 0;
    return S_ISDIR(s.st_mode);
}
int borrar_Directorio (char *nom){
    DIR *directorio = opendir(nom);
    struct dirent *direntd ;
    char nombre[MAX];
    int aux;

    if (directorio == NULL) //No se puede abrir
        return -1;
    while ((direntd = readdir(directorio))!= NULL){
        if (!strcmp(direntd ->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(direntd -> d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        sprintf (nombre, "%s %s", nom, direntd -> d_name);
        aux = EsDirectorio(nombre)? borrar_Directorio(nombre):  unlink(nombre); 

        if (aux == -1){ //Comprobar si es un directorio
            perror(nombre);
            break;
        }   
    }
    closedir(directorio);
    return rmdir (nom);
}

void eliminate (char *trozos[], int palabras){
    int i = 0;

    if ((trozos[0] != NULL) && (!strcmp(trozos[0], "-f"))){
        i = 1;
        trozos++;
    }
    if (palabras == 1){
        printf("No se ha introducido ningun fichero o directorio\n");
        return;
    }
    else if (palabras ==2){
        if (!i){    
            if (remove(trozos[1]) == -1)
            printf("imposible borrar %s\n", trozos[1]);
        }
        else if (borrar_Directorio(trozos[1])== -1)
            printf("imposible borrar %s\n", trozos[1]);
    }
    else if (palabras == 3){
        if (!i){    
            if (remove(trozos[2]) == -1)
                printf("imposible borrar %s\n", trozos[2]);    
        }
        if (borrar_Directorio(trozos[2])== -1)
            printf("imposible borrar %s\n", trozos[2]);
    }
}

void procesarEntrada(char *entrada, int *encontrado){
    char *trozos[MAX];
    int palabras;
    palabras=TrocearCadena(entrada,trozos);
    if (palabras>0){
        if (strcmp(trozos[0],"autores")==0)
            autores(trozos,palabras);

        else if (strcmp(trozos[0],"pid")==0)
            pid(trozos,palabras);

        else if ((strcmp(trozos[0],"end")==0) || (strcmp(trozos[0],"fin")==0) || (strcmp(trozos[0],"exit")==0))
            *encontrado=0;  

        else if (strcmp(trozos[0],"info")==0)
            info(trozos,palabras);

        else if (strcmp(trozos[0],"recursive")==0)
            recursive(trozos,palabras);

        else if (strcmp(trozos[0],"eliminate")==0)
            eliminate(trozos,palabras);

        else printf("Comando desconocido \n");
    }
}
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿ Que significa `no me deja` ? ¿ No borra nada ? ¿ Borrar archivos pero no directorios ? ¿ Da algún error ?

Comment: Perdón, me explique mal, lo que quería decir es que cuando pongo eliminate -f directorio no me elimina el directorio y su contenido, si no que me saca el mensaje : "imposible borrar (como se llame el directorio)".

Comment: ¿ Has puesto el código **exacto** ? Porque el que muestras **entra en bucle**, ya que solo llamas a `readdir( )` **1 sola vez**, antes de entrar en el `while( )`. No llegará ni siquiera a devolver `-1`.

Comment: Si es el código exacto. Entonces debería poner el readdir() en el while?

Comment: Quita el `readdir( )` de donde está, y ponlo así: `while( ( direntd = readdir(directorio) ) )`. Así por lo menos te leerá mas de 1 entrada. Ya nos contarás :-)

Comment: Ahora cuando pongo eliminate -f directorio me sale por pantalla el mensaje: "imposible borrar (nombre directorio)" del remove(trozos[2]). Después el mensaje de la función borrar_directorio, el sprintf. Y por último: "imposible borrar (nombre directorio)" de borrar_Directorio(trozos[2])

Comment: Respecto al anterior comentario, el mensaje que me sale, aparte del sprintf es el perror. Sale "sprintf : no such file or directory"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolución del código:

```
int borrarContenidoDirectorio (char *nom){
    DIR *directorio = opendir(nom);
    size_t path_lon = strlen(nom);
    int r = -1;
    if (directorio){
        struct dirent *direntd;
        r = 0;
        while (!r && (direntd =readdir(directorio))){
            int r2 = -1;
            char *buf;
            size_t lon;
            if (!strcmp(direntd ->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(direntd -> d_name, ".."))
                continue;
            lon = path_lon + strlen(direntd -> d_name) + 20;
            buf = malloc(lon);
            if (buf){
                struct stat statbuf;
                int aux;
                snprintf(buf, lon, "%s/%s", nom, direntd -> d_name);
                aux = EsDirectorio(buf);
                if (!stat(buf, &statbuf)){
                    if (EsDirectorio(buf))
                        r2 = borrarContenidoDirectorio(buf);
                    else 
                        r2 = unlink(buf); //borra nombre S.F    
                    if (aux == -1){ //Comprobar si es un directorio
                        perror(buf);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                free(buf);
            }
            r = r2;
        }
        closedir(directorio);
    }   
    if (!r)
      r= rmdir (nom);    
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Hola Gilbert, esto es una respuesta a tu pregunta?

Comment: Si. El problema que tenia era que la función borrar_Directorio no me borraba el contenido del directorio y después el directorio. Pero esta función (borrarContenidoDirectorio) ya si.

Comment: pues has de explicar mejor la respuesta. Para futuros users con problemas parecidos. Mira [answer]